# import products using fast_simple_import

Tags: magento-1.9, import-products

Anyone know a stable way to import thousands of products to magento using fast_ simple_import and syncing updates from external POS without relying on SKUs?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 3):

**Refer below for steps to import products in magento 1 version**

> https://www.magestore.com/manage-magento-online-store/magento-import-products

You may refer to good extensions for product import like [Import Export Products](https://marketplace.magento.com/magebees-import-products-categories-multiple-images-and-custom-options.html)